# Breadcrumbs not appearing in SharePoint 2013

Tags: breadcrumb

Folks,

Adding Breadcrumbs doesn't appears on the Intranet page running on SharePoint 2013.
Modified the seattle.master file, value changed:

Delete the style=”display:none;” at the end of the line.
Rename the Visible=”true” immediately underneath.

Still it doesnt works, please help.

Comment: Will need some more information. Was it working before you modified seattle.master?

What else did you edit on the master page? What was the purpose of the edits?

Answer (score 0):

Got the breadcrumb after following the 2 articles.

Following :

http://jenasaswati.blogspot.hk/2013/12/breadcrumb-navigation-in-sharepoint-2013.html

&

http://blog.sharepointexperience.com/2015/08/sharepoint-2013-breadcrumb/

Comment: You can extract some important details from the link and post it. Links may break in future.